# install robotframework-datadriver 0.3.3 but get the following error: "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: robotframework

I have tried to install `robotframework-datadriver` via the command below:

```
pip install robotframework-datadriver
```

but I got error

> python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade `setuptools` by this command

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

and try to install robotframework-datadriver again.

If you already have Python >= 3.6 with pip installed, you can simply run:

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-datadriver
```

Comment: i got the same error "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c0h6xyv1\pandas

Comment: what's python version you are using ?

Comment: python version 3.8

Comment: If you already have Python >= 3.6 with pip installed, you can simply run:
pip install --upgrade robotframework-datadriver